# Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and membership algorithms

Tags: measure-theory, computability, borel-sets

**Edit**: As the comments by many people show, the answer is no, and my argument for open sets is wrong. Still, I believe that my mistakes are interesting, so I'm not going to delete the question.

Fix a Borel subset $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$.

Is there an algorithm that takes $x \in \mathbb{R}$ as input and decides whether $x$ belongs to $B$?
The algorithm is allowed to make queries of the form "Compare $x$ to $y$" for $y\in\mathbb{R}$. The result of such a query is one of $<$, $=$ and $>$.

Note that $B$ is arbitrary but fixed. It is not part of the input of the algorithm.

If $B$ is open, such an algorithm exists: First we can find an integer $T$ such that $|x|\leq T$. Then it remains to decide whether or not $x$ belongs to one of finitely many open intervals.

Note that my notion of an algorithm is allowed to have real numbers as variables and perform arithmetic operations on them.

My notion of an algorithm is also allowed to have a pre-computed infinite sequence of real values in memory (for my example where $B$ is open, I'm assuming that the endpoints of the intervals whose union is $B$ are stored in memory before the algorithm starts running, in a convenient order).

My general motivation here is my intuition that in some sense Borel sets are "computable". I haven't decided exactly what this means yet, but the question above depicts my first attempt.

For this reason, if you think there's a similar more interesting question, please let me know.

Comment: Interesting, but for example if $x \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ I don't see how the algorithm can conclude that $x$ belongs to such set by comparing it to other real numbers (unless I am not getting the full picture).

Comment: @Snoop: Yes, you are right. It seems implausible that this can be done. I did not think of that.

Comment: What model of computation are we using? We need to store infinite amounts of information to store an arbitrary real number, so probably not Turing machines

Comment: @DavidLui: I'm thinking of machines similar to Turing machines, but storing a real number in each cell. And also being able to perform arithmetic operations on the real values stored in the cells.

Comment: So, formally your algorithm is sequence of real numbers + Turing Machine that can make calls "compare $x$ to $i$-th number in this sequence"? Then take any $x$ not in this sequence, TM makes finite number of comparisons, thus $x$ has some neighbourhood where calls and results for them will be the same, thus answer will be the same. And if $x$ is limit for both $B$ and $\overline{B}$ then there are points in this neighbourhood where answer will be wrong.

Comment: Your argument for the computability of open sets has two errors. First, there is a topological error: consider, for example, the complement of the Cantor set, which is open and has infinitely many connected components in a finite interval. Second, even ignoring such open sets, you have an issue with **uniformity** - consider the set $$\bigcup_{n\in K}(2k, 2k+1)$$ where $K$ is the halting problem. You need the open set to be "computably presented" in an appropriately strong sense (or allow an arbitrary real number as a parameter).

Comment: @mihaild: This is interesting. My algorithm can also perform arithmetic operations one this sequence and put the result in a new cell, but I think your argument extends to this model too.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Thank you. Regarding your parenthetical remark: Can you elaborate a bit on how a real parameter helps?

Comment: @Object I'll try to later when I get time. BTW re: your edit please don't delete this question, it's quite a good one!

Comment: I think allowing arithmetic doesn't help. It's the same as allowing to ask asking "if given rational function of $x$ and first $k$ variables with integer coefficients is non-negative". But there are only countable many such functions, each of them as function of $x$ changes sign finitely many times, and we can just give the points where the function changes sign to the TM.